# How to export group membership list

Tags: windows-server-2003

How do I export a list of all groups and the users who are members of each of the groups on a Windows 2003 server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an individual server, `net localgroup` would display a list of all local groups. Then, run `net localgroup <name>` for each group, I'm not going to write that .BAT file for you :-)

On an AD domain, `dsquery group | dsget group -members`